# Clarification between "rolling your own cryptography" vs "implementing a specification"

Tags: discussion, cryptography

There seems to be a general consensus that people shouldn't implement their own cryptography but rather rely on pre-existing standards.

Should we permit questions that discuss implementing a standard (AES, PGP, etc) in contrast to homebrew crypto that isn't affiliated (or diverges from) a known standard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Where the implementation is something a security professional has to be aware of, then this should be on-topic, however if it is the case that the question is purely a coding one (ie it isn't about security decisions, but is about coding or configuration) then I would feel it would be offtopic here, but possibly better served on SO, SF, SU or even one of the specific sites such as Ask, Android etc.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, if it is about the details of the algorithm, then it would be better on Crypto.

Comment: Seems like how the algorithm works is crypto, how the algorithm is used is Security and how the algorithm is implemented is StackOverflow.

Comment: @AJHenderson and whether [hipster language of the week] is the "best" language for implementing it is Programmers.