# Are questions about cryptography migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic, cryptography

I still see that a lot of questions that are directly and only about cryptography and cryptographic schemes are kept here, while I'm regularly migrating questions to security.SE when they are on the broader subject of security rather than *just* cryptography.

Would you please be so kind to flag & migrate such questions to our site rather than keeping them here? Otherwise we get lots of duplicates, and the questions may not get the attention from our core of crypto experts.

---

Examples when I hit the cryptography tag are:

[How long should a hash be to be absolutely secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222419/how-long-should-a-hash-be-to-be-absolutely-secure)
[Is FeliCa DES encryption safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221724/is-felica-des-encryption-safe)
[Is it bad practice to reuse private EC key as a shared secret for a symmetric algorithm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221243/is-it-bad-practice-to-reuse-private-ec-key-as-a-shared-secret-for-a-symmetric-al)
[Outcome of Needham-Schroeder protocol](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220530/outcome-of-needham-schroeder-protocol)
[Do integrity and authentication always come together?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220309/do-integrity-and-authentication-always-come-together)

...and so on...

And these are just the ones for which I'm pretty sure they are *just* about crypto without involving anything else.

Fortunately I see fewer problems with the encryption tag, as most of those questions are relatively application specific - i.e. more on the practical application of crypto - and/or more broad.

---

Fact remains that I almost never see anything migrated from Security.SE or StackOverflow (and from StackOverflow only when I flag the questions myself, and then still not most of the time).

As a friendly reminder, this is from this meta site:

[Difference between security stackexchange and cryptography stackexchange?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1503/2651)

and the quote from AJ Henderson from [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/clarification-between-rolling-your-own-cryptography-vs-implementing-a-specifi#comment2762_1120)

> Seems like how the algorithm works is crypto, how the algorithm is used is Security and how the algorithm is implemented is StackOverflow.

although I think that questions on how crypto schemes interact is probably also best answered at cryptography.

Comment: [Do integrity and authentication always come together?][1] seems really borderline though. We are not just about technical implementation and application. Security is an emergent property that often requires conceptual analysis. I'm not sure, even in the light of your comments, that I would migrate it. What model would you use to migrate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been cases where I have migrated based on that model and it has been rejected.

Although, I am happy to start fresh and see where we need to find a happy medium.

Comment: I guess that questions about algorithms, how algorithms interact and specific cryptanalysis should be migrated. Other questions about crypto will often be in a grey area. It is not my intention to make a fuzz about that. If crypto is mainly in the answer and not in the question then it should remain here; other answers are then possible after all. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Hey schroeder, thanks for the influx of on topic migrated questions, much appreciated. Just give me or one of the other mods like the 'tater a shout if anything is off with migration!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the feedback. I'm certainly content with the process if you are.